# issue with uploading to TestPyPI more than once

Tags: python, package, pypi

I've been following the procedure for uploading to TestPyPi highlighted here 
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

First time round i stupidly got the directory setup incorrect. And i couldn't properly download my package. So i decided to do it again this time using a different name for my main directory and package directory. However when i now try to run the same code i get the following error

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: user **** isn't allowed to upload to project 'example-pkg- 
your-username'. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#project-name for more 
information. for url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Does anyone have any idea why this won't allow me to upload? I've even tried creating a new username. One thing i tried changing is two of the details in setup.py namely the name and version, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your project name from `example-pkg-your-username` in `setup.py` and rebuild the distribution, as it's already been used by someone else.

Comment: i still get the same error, or were you talking about a different variable?

Comment: setuptools.setup(
    name="pavansanghas_pkg-psangha",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="******@hotmail.co.uk",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)

Comment: No where can i see example-pkg-your-username

Comment: solved it, i didn't recreate the distribution packages once i'd changed the name